# Flutter - custom font family doesn't apply to the app

Tags: flutter, dart, fonts

Im trying to set a new default font to my flutter app however the font still remains the same, it still uses the default font that came with flutter.

Here is my pubspec.yaml file

```
fonts:
    - family: Rajdhani
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Rajdhani-Regular.ttf
        - asset: fonts/Rajdhani-Bold.ttf
```

And this is my main.dart file

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: DriverScreen()));

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Formula 1',
      home: DriverScreen(),
      theme: ThemeData(fontFamily: 'Rajdhani')
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You have used 2 ``MaterialApp`` widgets in your app. You should have only one widget per app. Remove either one and it'll work.

Comment: Also, ``MyApp`` isn't referenced anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used 2 `MaterialApp` widgets in your app. You should have only one widget per app.

And now to fix your issue:

`void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: DriverScreen()));`

Should be

`void main() => runApp(MyApp());`

Because `MyApp` isn't referenced yet as per your implementation, which isn't setting the default font.

Comment: i have one more question on how to make some of my text widget bold, because even though ive used the textweight.bold method it still doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

try to run the command flutter pub get again and if it didn't work verify the path of your fonts folder.